# C Regex - Get matched string

Tags: c, regex

I have this code:

```
regex_t regex;
    int reti;

    reti = regcomp(&regex, "[0-9]", REG_EXTENDED);

    reti = regexec(&regex, "sdsda5dada", 0, NULL, 0);
    if( !reti ){
        return 1;
    }
    else if( reti == REG_NOMATCH ){
        return 0;
    }

    regfree(&regex);
```

Which matches the number *5* contained in the string `sdsda5dada`. How can I get into a variable the matched part? Let's say I have a `char *` variable called `matchd_str`, how can I put *5* into that variable?

I know it's a very noob question, but I don't know much about regex. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`man regexec` states:

```
The 0th member of the pmatch array is filled in to indicate what substring
of string was matched by the entire RE. Remaining members report what
substring was matched by parenthesized subexpressions within the RE.
```

Thus you have to point the `pmatch` argument to an array of `regmatch_t` of at least one element, and set nmatch to the size of pmatch. The `rm_so` and `rm_se` fields of `pmatch[0]` will then point out the matching part of the string:

```
 const char *string = "sdsda5dada";
 const char *digit_start = string + pmatch[0].rm_so;
 const char *digit_end = string + pmatch[0].rm_se;
 int digit_len = digit_end - digit_start;
```

It's not NUL terminated, if you want a proper C string you will have to copy it, e.g.:

```
 char digit_copy[10];

 if (digit_len >= sizeof(digit_copy))
     digit_len = sizoef(digit_copy) - 1;
 memcpy(digit_copy, digit_start, digit_len);
 digit_copy[digit_len] = '\0';
```

`nmatch` is the third argument and `patch` the fourth. Here's the synopsis:

```
 int
 regexec(const regex_t *restrict preg, const char *restrict string, size_t nmatch, regmatch_t pmatch[restrict],
     int eflags);
```

Comment: How do I typecast from `regmatch_t` to `char *`?

Comment: That's also described in the man page, but I expanded the answer